# How to remove a "List of items" from a list?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have two lists : `_bufferCarnetList`  and `_deletedWords`.
When the user hits OK: I want to remove from `_bufferCarnetList` the items contained in `_deletedWords`.

I have tried using the `.remove` method, but nothing happens.

```
_bufferCarnetList.remove(_deletedWords).
```

Is there a way to do it in a direct way, or should I iterate the list and remove each item separately ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `removeWhere` method:

```dart
_bufferCarnetList.removeWhere((e) => _deletedWords.contains(e));
```